# command subsitution doesn't work when issued from ssh

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, wireguard

I have an Ubuntu vps to which I connect from my laptop that also runs Ubuntu.

When I ssh root@server to my server I can successfully run the following command:

```
root@server:~# wg set wg0 peer $(cat /etc/wireguard/clients/guard001_pub) remove
```

but when I do not want to login and just want to run the command remotely I get a permission denied error which I do not understand why. Because the file owned by root and has all rwx permissions.

```
username@mymachine:~$ ssh root@server "wg set wg0 peer $(cat /etc/wireguard/clients/guard001_pub) remove"
```

gives the following error:

```
cat: /etc/wireguard/clients/guard001_pub: Permission denied
Key is not the correct length or format: `remove'
```

Can anyone tell why is this happening and what is the best workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you surrounded the command with double quotes, `$(cat /etc/wireguard/clients/guard001_pub)` gets evaluated by your *local* shell, before the `ssh` command is run.

Since the local `cat /etc/wireguard/clients/guard001_pub` fails, the local command substitution results in an empty string, and the remote command becomes

```
wg set wg0 peer remove
```

so that `remove` gets passed as the key.

Instead, use single quotes:

```
ssh root@server 'wg set wg0 peer $(cat /etc/wireguard/clients/guard001_pub) remove'
```

or perhaps better

```
ssh root@server 'wg set wg0 peer "$(cat /etc/wireguard/clients/guard001_pub)" remove'
```